# Python Function Decorators in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, decorator

I'm having trouble using python function decorators in Google's AppEngine.  I'm not that familiar with decorators, but they seem useful in web programming when you might want to force a user to login before executing certain functions.

Anyway, I was following along with a flickr login example [here](http://stuvel.eu/flickrapi/documentation/#example-using-django) that uses django and decorates a function to require the flickr login.  I can't seem to get this type of decorator to work in AppEngine.

I've boiled it down to this:

```
def require_auth(func):
    def check_auth(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Authenticated."
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return check_auth

@require_auth
def content():
    print "Release sensitive data!"

content()
```

This code works from the commandline, but when I run it in GoogleAppEngineLauncher (OS X), I get the following error:

```
check_auth() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

And I'm not really sure why...

EDIT to include actual code: 
@asperous.us I changed the definition of content() to include variable arguments, is that what you meant?
@Alex Martelli, 'print' does work within AppEngine, but still a completely fair criticism.
Like I said, I'm trying to use the flickr login from the link above.  I tried to put it into my app like so:

```
def require_flickr_auth(view):
    def protected_view(request,*args, **kwargs):
        if 'token' in request.session:
            token = request.session['token']
            log.info('Getting token from session: %s' % token)
        else:
            token = None
            log.info('No token in session')

        f = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret,
                                token=token, store_token=False)

        if token:
            # We have a token, but it might not be valid
            log.info('Verifying token')
            try:
                f.auth_checkToken()
            except flickrapi.FlickrError:
                token = None
                del request.session['token']

        if not token:
            # No valid token, so redirect to Flickr
            log.info('Redirecting user to Flickr to get frob')
            url = f.web_login_url(perms='read')
            print "Redirect to %s" % url

        # If the token is valid, we can call the decorated view.
        log.info('Token is valid')
        return view(request,*args, **kwargs)

    return protected_view

@require_flickr_auth
def content(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'Welcome, oh authenticated user!'

def main():
    print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
    content()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I remove the @require_flickr_auth decoration, the string 'Welcome ...' prints out just fine.  Otherwise I get a big ugly AppEngine exception page with

```
type 'exceptions.TypeError': protected_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `content()` without any arguments, but the decorated version `protected_view` requires the `request` argument. Either add the argument to `content` or remove it from `protected_view`.

If you're getting that error with your simple version then I'd suspect that `content` is a class method as Alex suggested. Otherwise it looks like you're telling it to expect at least one argument, then not supplying it any.

Comment: Doh - That's totally it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Owen, the "takes at least 1 argument" error suggests you're defining content within a class (i.e. as a method) and not as a bare function as you show -- indeed, how exactly are you trying to execute that code in GAE?  I.e. what's your app.yaml &c? If you put your code exactly as you gave it in `silly.py` and in your app.yaml you have:

```
handlers:
- url: /silly
  script: silly.py
```

then when you visit `yourapp.appspot.com/silly` you will see absolutely nothing on either the browser or the logs (besides the `"GET /silly HTTP/1.1" 200 -` in the latter of course;-): there is no error but the `print` doesn't DO anything in particular either. So I have to imagine you tried running code different from what you're showing us...!-)

Answer (score 0):

Decorators were added in python 2.4 (I think), maybe googleapp is using an older version?
You can also do:

```
def content():
    print "Release sensitive data!"
    content = require_auth(content)
```

it will do the same thing as the decorator, it is just a little more work.

Comment: Yeah, or at least the syntax changed or something? At any rate,  the AppEngine site claims that the python version is 2.5.2.

Comment: You would think that I could do that, right? But content = require_auth(content) gives the same error...

Comment: @Owen, see my answer below...!

Answer (score 0):

Why

`return func(*args, **kwargs)`

wouldn't that execute func and then return the result?

If so, you shouldn't give it any arguments, since it doesn't take any. If you edited content() and added the `(*args, **kwargs)` arguments onto it, will it work?